# Resolve Dereference of a possibly null reference for a nullable array of nullable objects

Tags: c#, c#-8.0, nullable-reference-types

In the code below I get a both a CS8602 and CS8605 even if I check the not null condition for all the terms. How can I avoid the warning?

```
public class TestNullable
{ 
    private object? obj = null;
    public object? Obj { get => obj; set => obj = value; }

}
internal class Program
{
    static TestNullable?[]? tests = null;

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        tests = new TestNullable[2];

        int[] listOfInts1 = new int[] { 1, 2, 3 };
        int[] listOfInts2 = new int[] { 3, 4, 5 };
        tests[0] = new TestNullable() { Obj = listOfInts1 };
        tests[1] = new TestNullable() { Obj = listOfInts2 };

    }

    public static int selectIndex(int index)
    {
        if(tests != null && tests[index] != null && tests[index].Obj != null) // CS8602
            return (int)tests[index].Obj; // CS8605
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would suggest looking into [null conditional operators](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/member-access-operators#null-conditional-operators--and-) with some typechecking:

```cs
public static int selectIndex(int index)
{
    if(tests?[index]?.Obj is int i)
        return i; 
    return 0;
}
```

P.S.

You might want to check the array length also.

Comment: I mark this as the answer because I like very much the very concise syntax

Answer (score 1):

Personally, I really like pattern matching.
It does triple duty here by null checking, type checking, and assigning to variable.
I put this into a console app to test-run it and noticed a couple of other things, such as the need for second index argument for this to make sense.

```
internal class Program
{
    static TestNullable?[]? tests = null;

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        tests = new TestNullable[2];

        int[] listOfInts1 = new int[] { 1, 2, 3 };
        int[] listOfInts2 = new int[] { 3, 4, 5 };
        tests[0] = new TestNullable() { Obj = listOfInts1 };
        tests[1] = new TestNullable() { Obj = listOfInts2 };

        Console.WriteLine("Hello World " + selectIndex(0, 2));
        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    public static int selectIndex(int index, int secondIndex)
    {
        if (tests != null && tests[index] != null)
        {
            if (tests[index] is TestNullable test)
            {
                if (test.Obj is int[] array)
                {
                    return array[secondIndex];
                }
            }
        }
        return 0;
    }
}
```

[image: output]

Answer (score 0):

The reason for this warning is because each access to an array element (`tests[index]`) is independent, and the analyzer believes it.

You need a middle variable to pass the nullable test:

```
public static int selectIndex(int index)
{
    if(tests == null)
        return 0;
    
    var obj = tests[index];
    if(obj != null && obj.Obj != null)
        return (int)obj.Obj;
    return 0;
}
```

You can also use the null-forgiving operator `!`:

```
public static int selectIndex(int index)
{
    if(tests != null && tests[index] != null && tests[index]!.Obj != null)
        return (int)tests[index]!.Obj!;
    return 0;
}
```